# Повторяющиеся значения soap wsdl

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

я создаю веб-сервис для отправки данных - soap вместе с wsdl.

Как мне отправить запрос с повторяющимися значениями?

К примеру, в wsdl-схеме я написал так:

```
<xs:complexType name="pupilsList">
                    <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Список учащихся</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>

                    <xs:sequence>

                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="pupil" type="tns:pupil"/>

                    </xs:sequence>

                    </xs:complexType>
```

Тоесть внутри мне нужно передать множество подобных элементов - pupil. Но как это сделать?

Я передаю данные ассоциативным массивом, а в нём не записать одинаковых ключей.

Вот пример данных, которые я отправляю -  array ("pupilsList" =>

```
        array ("pupil"=>
        array ("regid"=>$school,"suid"=>55578,"surname"=>"ERcxcxc","name"=>"xfdfdf","patronymic"=>"sdfs","class"=>"10 A","dob"=>"207-01-01","cardDataList"=>
        array("cardInfo"=>
        array ("cardData"=>"777777","cardRFID"=>"67777777","cardType"=>"1","cardTypeOper"=>"4567","benefit"=>
        array ("code"=>1,"adate"=>"2018-12-12","bdate"=> "2018-12-12")))), "pupil_2" => array ("regid"=>$school,"suid"=>55575,"surname"=>"ERcxcxc","name"=>"xfdfdf","patronymic"=>"sdfs","class"=>"10 A","dob"=>"207-01-01","cardDataList"=>
        array("cardInfo"=>
        array ("cardData"=>"777777","cardRFID"=>"67777777","cardType"=>"1","cardTypeOper"=>"4567","benefit"=>
        array ("code"=>1,"adate"=>"2018-12-12","bdate"=>"2018-12-12")))), "pupil_500" => array ("regid"=>$school,"suid"=>55575,"surname"=>"ERcxcxc","name"=>"xfdfdf","patronymic"=>"sdfs","class"=>"10 A","dob"=>"207-01-01","cardDataList"=>
        array("cardInfo"=>
        array ("cardData"=>"777777","cardRFID"=>"67777777","cardType"=>"1","cardTypeOper"=>"4567","benefit"=>
        array ("code"=>1,"adate"=>"2018-12-12","bdate"=>"2018-12-12")))) ),"datetime"=>"2018-12-12");
```

Вот один элемент pupil:

```
<xs:complexType name="pupil">
                    <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="regid" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="suid" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="surname" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="patronymic" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="klass" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="dob" type="xs:date"/>
                    <xs:element name="cardDataList" type="tns:cardDataList"/>

                    </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
```

Пробовал под ключом pupil передавать массив данных, но выходит ошибка. Не соответствие wsdl-схеме. Внутри нет соответствующих свойств.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать что в этом случае может сработать?

Comment: Для отправки запроса на SOAP сервис вам нужно отправлять XML, а не сериализованный массив.

Comment: Однако такой массив успешно преобразуется в xml.

Comment: Как можно отправить по другому? Можете привести пример?